# Find arrays into PHP document?

Tags: php, arrays

There is a way to find all the arrays stored into a PHP document?

If I have:

```
$one = array();
$two = array();
$foo = array();
```

How can I get a list of them into an array like:

```
$arrays = array($one, $two, $foo);
```

?

Comment: Is there an example of a practical application where this solves a specific problem?

Comment: I have a list of arrays that populate a list in a website and I need to get the same list but for different purposes in another page without know which one are the defined arrays

Comment: Did you not define the arrays you intend to use?

Comment: Yes I did, but in an included doc

Comment: Then separate your code into three parts: one where you generate those arrays, preferably a function, and two other parts that use that function.

Comment: okay but I don't know how many arrays I have, and them are hand written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php):

> array get_defined_vars ( void )
>
> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of
>   all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined
>   variables, within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called.

As it will show up all the environment, server and your variables, you need to "grep" those you want.

Comment: Thanks but what if the document is not the one where I'm working but it's just included? If I include it them will be mixed with the ones of the document where I'm working and I've no ways to know which one is from the external document...

Comment: didn't know this function existed. but if you're grepping for the variables you want, this means that you know what variables you want. Wouldn't it make more sense to just work with them directly in that case?

Comment: Good point, @kennypu. Maybe a `grep -v` way: delete all HTTP variables we know are always set, so the ones that stay are the ones we define.

Comment: I may get the defined vars before included the document and then after and make a difference between them?

Comment: Well, you can fetch `get_defined_vars()` before and after including the document, so the difference will be the new ones.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, I suppose if you can remove all the environmental variables, this would be a good solution.

Comment: This will only work within the scope the checking is made or within the global scope if you use the `$_GLOBAL` variable.