# List all arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, list

Is there a method or function in PHP which can list out all the arrays and their content that are currently in memory?  I'm trying to track down a problem in someone else's code that used CodeIgniter and I'm not having a lot of success.

Comment: Use a debugger for debugging.

Comment: [Find arrays into PHP document?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19266521/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get_defined_vars()` function, reference the [manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

```
var_dump( get_defined_vars () );
```

Comment: Maybe the dv was because you are not isolating all arrays as required in the task description. This answer dumps all variables out.

Answer (score 2):

Loop defined vars and check for arrays:

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $var => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo $var;
        var_dump($val);
    }
}
```